# Fetch the value of ajax loaded select box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am populating the div with a select box using AJAX.
But, I am unable to access the value of it, via jquery.

I think, that's because the select box is loaded via AJAX. Please let me know how to access the value of it, on keypress of a textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Select.php",
            data:"query=class?serch=",
            success:function(result){
                $("#drpExclass").html(result);
                    var w =     document.re_register.ex_class.selectedIndex; 
var selected_text = document.re_register.ex_class.options[w].text; 
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Select.php",
            data:"getnxt="+selected_text,
            success:function(result){
                $("#drpNextclass").html(result);
            /* $("#drpNextclass").html(result);*/

                }
            });
                }
            });      
});
```

The dropNExtClass gets the refreshed select box. Now, i am trying to get the value of the select for the autocomplete query string.

Comment: Code maybe ? I don't understand..

Comment: Please provide the code how you are populating the Select box.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"Select.php",
    data:"query=class?serch=",
    success:function(result){
     $("#drpExclass").html(result);
      var w = document.re_register.ex_class.selectedIndex; 
var selected_text = document.re_register.ex_class.options[w].text; 
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"Select.php",
    data:"getnxt="+selected_text,
    success:function(result){
     $("#drpNextclass").html(result);
    /* $("#drpNextclass").html(result);*/
    
     }
     });
     }
     });   
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provide any code I assume you have to do something like this :-

```
$( "#text_box_id" ).on("keypress",function() 
{

      var value = $('#select_box_id').val();


});
```

Comment: Done. I found the solution